# Creating an array with characters and incrementing numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab

Pretty simple problem, I want to create an array with char in a for loop.

code:

```
a = [1:5];
arr = [];
for i = 1:length(a)
    arr(i) = ['f_',num2str(i)]
end
```

I am getting error:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

all i want is an array:

```
[f_1 f_2 f_3....]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `arr(i)` is a single element, while `['f:', num2str(i)]` contain three characters. Also, `for i = 1:length(1)` doesn't really make sense, since `length(1)` is guaranteed to be `1`. I guess you wanted `for i = 1:length(a)`. If that's the case I suggest you substitute `length` with `numel` and `i` with `ii`.

The better way to create the array you want is using `sprintf` like this:

```
sprintf('f_%i\n',1:5)
ans =
f_1
f_2
f_3
f_4
f_5
```

Or possiblby:

```
sprintf('f_%i ',1:5)    
ans =    
f_1 f_2 f_3 f_4 f_5
```

I guess this is what you really wanted:

```
for ii = 1:5
    arr{ii} = ['f_', num2str(ii)];
end
arr =     
    'f_1'    'f_2'    'f_3'    'f_4'    'f_5'
```

Or simpler:

```
arr = arrayfun(@(n) sprintf('f_%i', n), 1:5, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

The last two can be indexed as follows:

```
arr{1}    
ans =    
f_1
```

You can also do (same result):

```
str = sprintf('f_%i\n', 1:5);
arr = strsplit(str(1:end-1), '\n')
```

If you're doing this to create variable names, then please don't. Use cells or structs instead.

Comment: Sorry, typing error. I wanted to write 'for i = 1:length(a)'